# How to clear wpColorPicker (Iris.js)?

Tags: color-picker

I'm trying to clear the [WordPress colorpicker](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) but seems it doesn't work. This is what I'Ve tried:

```
$('#element').wpColorPicker('clear');
//error: Uncaught Error: no such method 'clear' for wpColorPicker widget instance
$('#element').wpColorPicker('color', '#');
//no output/change  
$('#element').wpColorPicker('color', '');
//no output/change
```

Of course there's no method mentioned in [the documentation](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/#methods) but there's a options for a callback method so it's maybe possible via some "hacking"?

Comment: How about this documentation. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/

Comment: not really helpful in this case

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: not really, I've updated my question

Comment: Please add more code. How do you trigger the `wpColorPicker`? On `document_ready` handler? Additionally please ensure if jquery enqueued before colorpicker scripts and both libs loads well.

Comment: yes sure `$('#element').wpColorPicker('color', '#bada55');` works great as well the other methods. I just wonder if there is even a way to reset it

Answer (score 1):

This is hacky but gets the job done.

```
$('#element .wp-picker-clear').trigger('click');
```